# Best way to surround an HTML <q> element with single quotation marks

Tags: html, css

On using the  HTML element, I want quotes to be displayed with 'single quotation marks' instead of "double quotation marks", as is standard practice in British English.

Markup:

```
<q>a bad system will beat a good person every time.<q>
```

Result:
"a bad system will beat a good person every time."

Desired Result:
'a bad system will beat a good person every time.'

What is the most elegant way to solve this? I am thinking of a CSS rule for quotation marks. How does one write that?

Comment: CSS has a [`quotes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/quotes) property just for that.

Answer (score 5):

If you inspect the `<q>` element you will see that the quotes are generated by pseudo-elements. Simply change them to whatever text or symbol you like.

```css
q::before {
  content: "'";
}

q::after {
  content: "'";
}
```

```html
<q>a bad system will beat a good person every time.</q>
```

Answer (score 0):

A "messy" alternative, containing character escapes, to the answer already provided.

```html
&lsquo;a bad system will beat a good person every time.&rsquo;
```